# Issue on safari while capturing image of html including signature canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs project and I am trying to capture the HTML for creating images including the canvas of signature. It's working on firefox and chrome but not safari. Image is generated with the empty canvas.

[React Signature Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas)

[Html To Image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image)

```
this.setState({ formInput: document.getElementById("form-pdf") }) 

generateImage(data) {
    const input = this.state.formInput;
    let apiService = new ApiServices();
    if (input) {
        await htmlToImage.toBlob(input)
            .then((blob) => {
                console.log(blob,'blob')
                let file = new File([blob], "image.png", { type: "image/png" })
                if (data) {
                    let body = new FormData();
                    apiService.http.post(this.getAPINames().Upload, body, {
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        },
                        timeout: 100000,
                    }).then(response => {
                        console.log("Success")
                    }).catch(failure => {
                        hideLoader();
                        if (isDev) {
                            console.log("on upload image error:", failure)
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (isDev) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem just with a double execution of the html-to-image  function, so in your case it could be like this:

```
generateImage(data) {
    const input = this.state.formInput;
    let apiService = new ApiServices();
    if (input) {
        await htmlToImage.toBlob(input)
            .then(function(){
                await htmlToImage.toBlob(input)
                .then((blob) => {
                    console.log(blob,'blob')
                    let file = new File([blob], "image.png", { type: "image/png" })
                    if (data) {
                        let body = new FormData();
                        apiService.http.post(this.getAPINames().Upload, body, {
                            headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                            },
                            timeout: 100000,
                        }).then(response => {
                            console.log("Success")
                        }).catch(failure => {
                            hideLoader();
                            if (isDev) {
                                console.log("on upload image error:", failure)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (isDev) {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                })
            })
    }
}
```